# Cadet 4 wire thermostat to multiple heaters diagram help?

Tags: thermostat, baseboard, electric-heat

I am in need of some help hooking up a couple cadet four wire thermostats to multiple heaters in different rooms The thermostat on the back has two red wires and two black wires L1 L2 T1 T2 I believe I have the concept of the wiring please correct me if I’m wrong with the thermostat I have six wires coming from the box in three separate locations 3 white and 3 black wires I am showing that one set of wire is from the power source. The other set of wire is traveling wire and the third set of wire is the load to the heater. My question is L1 goes to black hot L2 goes to white hot T1 goes to heater black and T2 goes to heater white do I install the traveling white and black to L1 L2 to the power source of the thermostat or do I connect to T1 T2 on the load to the heater thank you for any help with this configurations

Comment: What do you mean by "travelers"? That is commonly a reference to 3-way switches, but I don't know what it means here.

Comment: It is the black white wire that connects to the other thermostats in the other locations for a power source

Comment: This is also 240 heaters that these control

Comment: I wouldn't use the term travelers. But now I know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways that you can have three cables. (These are cables rather than sets of individual wires, because if they were individual wires then the second wire in each set would be black or red and not white. White is always neutral *except* in certain situations with cables, and 240V heaters is one of those situations. Note that the white wires should have a marking of black or red tape to indicate that they are hot and not neutral.)

##### One Heater Per Thermostat

I believe this is the case in this particular instance. Each thermostat controls just one heater. In this case, you use wire nuts to connect:

- thermostat L1 (line/hot) + incoming power (black) + ongoing power (black)
- thermostat L2 (line/hot) + incoming power (white) + ongoing power (white)
- thermostat T1 (switched hot) + heater power (black)
- thermostat T2 (switched hot) + heater power (white)

##### Two Heaters Per Thermostat

Each thermostat controls just two heaters. In this case, you use wire nuts to connect:

- thermostat L1 (line/hot) + incoming power (black)
- thermostat L2 (line/hot) + incoming power (white)
- thermostat T1 (switched hot) + heater 1 power (black) + heater 2 power (black)
- thermostat T2 (switched hot) + heater 1 power (white) + heater 2 power (white)

Due to space limitations, to produce more even heating around a room or other reasons, it is not that unusual to have one thermostat control two heaters. But it is also common to have two heaters in separate rooms, each with its own thermostat, sharing one circuit.

A 20A 240V circuit can produce up to 3,840W of heat (20A x 240V x 0.8). That can be 2 x 1,500W, 3 x 1,000W, etc. The heaters don't even have to be the same size - e.g., 2 x 1,500W + 1 x 750W.

Just keep in mind that while these heaters are great for occasional supplemental heat, they are cheap to install but expensive to run.

Comment: Thank u for the info that helps a lot I have a 240 20amp double breaker supplying power to a 1500W and 500W baseboard heater in the bedroom with one Thermostat then it is connected to a 1000W baseboard heater in the kitchen  with a thermostat then it travels to a hallway heater that is set at 900W with a thermostat then travels  to a 500w heater in the closet

Comment: Mind you not all heaters are active at once and I actually removed the bedroom 500w heater and 1000w kitchen heater not hooked up currently and installed a smaller heater with a built in thermostat in the baseboard heater

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that is 1500 + 500 + 1000 + 900 + 500 = 4,400. 4,400 > 3,840. Problem is that heaters are considered a continuous load, which gets an 80% derate. Breaker will *never* trip until a bit over 4,800W, but not safe to run on a regular basis > 3,840.